# jpa - why getter of id of lazy reference executes DataBase statement

Tags: hibernate, jpa, lazy-loading, getter

I have one uni-relation between Product and Parameter. (JavaAssistant is used for implementing lazy references. Code is executed in Spring-Container).

```
@Entity
public class Product extends AbstractEntity {

  @javax.persistence.ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @javax.persistence.JoinColumn(name = "parameterID")
  private Parameter parameter;

...
}
```

Now I exceute:

```
 1. Product p = em.find(Product.class, 1L);
 2. System.out.println(p.getParameter().getId())
```

And in logs i can see:

```
select ... **product1_.parameterID** as paramet11_38_ ... from Product product1_  where product1_.id=?
select parameter0_.id as id49_0_ ... from Parameter parameter0_ where parameter0_.id=?
```

Why Jpa executes query for 2nd line, when it knows id of parameter(because it read in the 1st line)? 
It should execute query when it is being asked for other attribute than id. Dont you think?
Why it acts like that? Can we force Hibernate to different behavior?

Environment:

- Hibernate 3.6.10 as a JPA provider
- Spring 3.1.0
- JavaAssistant is used for implementing lazy references

Comment: What do you think should happen when you simply call `System.out.println(p.getParameter())`? What should be printed? *Empty* `Parameter` object (because it wasn't loaded yet)? Hibernate is just a bit eager here.

Comment: I expect here to display Id without executing DB-Statement. Proxy should know own Id - and only Id before "resolving" any other attribute.

Comment: True, but shouldn't `toString()` (when calling `println()`) at least try to access all properties (not only `id`) thus triggering DB load? My point is, once you call `getParameter()`, Hibernate thinks you want whole object. Apparently it's not smart enough.

Comment: Sorry, I thougt that it is written: `System.out.println(p.getParameter().)`. It is ok that hibernate excute statement by call `System.out.println(p.getParameter())`. It should access all properties during `toString()`. I expect that Hibernate will not execute any DB query till the moment when I ask about any other attribute than Id. Do you know maybe how other jpa providers behave?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issues is registered as bug (https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3718).
Probably will be corrected in the future.